# Is $G \rightarrow G/P$ surjective on $K$-points over a local field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, local-fields

Let $K$ be a local field, $G$ a (connected) reductive $K$-group, and $P \le G$ a parabolic subgroup. Is the map $G(K) \rightarrow (G/P)(K)$ necessarily surjective, and, if so, then why?

Comment: Any smooth surjective morphism is surjective on $K$-points.

Comment: @abx: Nope, not so: consider $\mathrm{SL}_n(K) \rightarrow \mathrm{PGL}_n(K)$ (for $K$ of characteristic $0$) for one of many counterexamples.

Comment: @abx: For a more geometric example consider a smooth projective geometrically connected curve $X_0$ over the finite residue field $k$ of $K$ such that $X_0(k)$ is empty, and let $X$ be a proper flat lift of $X_0$ over $O_K$. The generic fiber $X_K$ is smooth, proper, and geometrically connected curve over $K$ with no $K$-points.

Comment: Even more explicit, how about the map $C\to \text{Spec}(\mathbb{R})$ where $C$ is the smooth projective conic defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$?

Comment: @DanielLitt, there is probably some sort of personality test inherent in the question of whether your example or QuestionMark's is the first one to come to mind.  :-)

Comment: @LSpice: In some sense, the two examples are of the same nature; QuestionMark's example is related to the non-vanishing of $H^1(K, \mu_n)$ whereas mine is related to the non-vanishing of $H^2(K, \mu_2)$.

Comment: @DanielLitt, probably I'm being foolish, but isn't the failure of surjectivity *always* measured by the non-vanishing of a first cohomology set (or at least the non-injectivity of a certain map on first cohomology sets)?

Comment: @LSpice: That's the case for maps which are quotients by free group actions (as in QuestionMark's example) but the situation is rather more complicated in general.  The sense in which my example is "cohomological" is that the curve in question exhibits a Severi-Brauer curve whose associated Brauer class (in $H^2(K, \mu_2)$) is non-trivial.

Comment: @DanielLitt, yes, of course you're right.  Thanks for clearing up my confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The map G(K) to (G/P)(K) is surjective over any field K. Here is a link to an explanation by Brian Conrad.
http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/249CS13Page/handouts/parsurj.pdf